Convert mpeg4 to mp4 (x265 + aac)
I have legacy mpeg4 videos that do not play on chromecast and would like to convert - I believe x265 will be the best option for me, so while attempting to convert, while I have video, I no longer have audio.  I attempted to convert the media with this command line:
f=somefile.mpeg4
ffmpeg -i $f -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 $f.x265
ffmpeg -i $f -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -map 0:a $f.x265
ffmpeg -i $f -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy $f.x265

The first and third command line work, but yield no audio stream.  The second one fails, complaining that an x265 video can only have 1 video stream.
My video looks like this:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'somefile.mpeg4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42isom3gp6
    creation_time   : 1970-01-03T01:38:05.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:22.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3565 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x2](eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 848x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 53:30], 3430 kb/s, 23.40 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-03T01:38:05.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x1](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-03T01:38:05.000000Z
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]


The thing that worked for me was to encode it twice, not ideal, but it works:
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp4
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -c:a copy out.mp4.mp4

Once I'm done, I remove the first file:
rm -f out.mp4
mv out.mp4.mp4 out.mp4

